# Dynamic routing in production not working in NextJs 14

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm working on a project that has dynamic routing, /details/[detailsId], when I npm run dev all the routes all the pages are being rendered and are working perfect, but when deploying the app the dynamic routes are not working.

I'm getting an error message that says :GET https://sitename/_next/static/chunks/app/(root)/details/%5BdetailsId%5D/page-26d9d4d16993f748.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), I'm deploying the app on cloudways.

This is the folder structure and how I have defined the dynamic route for the details :

[image: App folder structure]

This is the DetailsPage , I'm fetching store data from an external api and passing the data to the **CustomAccordion** and **DetailsForm** and these 2 components have the "use client":

```
import CustomAccordion from "@/components/customs/CustomAccordion";
import { HomeService } from "@/services/home/home.service";
import DetailsForm from "../components/DetailsForm";

interface Props {
params: {
detailsId: string;
};
}

const DetailsPage: React.FC<Props> = async ({ params }) => {
const response = await HomeService.storeDetails(Number(params.detailsId));
const store: Store = response.data;
return (
<div className="flex w-full h-full lg:flex-row flex-col gap-10 lg:gap-0 lg:w-[90%] lg:p- 
0 p-4">
  <div className="flex-1 h-screen flex items-start justify-center ">
    <div className="flex flex-col w-[30rem] items-center justify-center gap-6">
      {store.image && (
        <img
          src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_IMAGE_URL}/${store.image}`}
          className="w-full"
        />
      )}
        <CustomAccordion store={store} />
    </div>
   </div>

   <div className="flex-1">
      <DetailsForm store={store} />
   </div>
  </div>
  );
  };

export default DetailsPage;
```

If anyone is wondering how I'm routing to the **detailsId** page is that I'm using the **useRouter()** from **next/navigation** : `router.push(`/details/${data?.storeId}`);`

Another thing to mention is that the **detailsId** is being extracted from the params perfectly and the api is actually fetching the data

I have tried everything and nothing is solving the issue, what could be the problem, I'm pretty sure code wise everything is fine, what could be the issue and the solution to this.

Comment: @Abdul actually my folder structure is safe, I'm using the dynamic routing here so basically when I route to the details/detailsId it is basically saying details/17 or some any other id that I can extract, this route is working fine in dev mode even when I npm build and npm start , it is not working in production when I deploy it to cloudways